# Reading text file with multiple spaces and words in R

Tags: r, file, text, read.table

I'm trying to import a text file into R which has several columns separated by several spaces. It also contains words which are also separated by spaces.
I've tried a lot with the read.table() command. When I use sep = "" R recognises the columns but places each word in a separate column. I could combine these columns but different rows contain a different amounts of words.
Example of a row in the text file:

`123A456B789C0   RADIO PANEL         95-17       AB123        0       1
0987AB654321C   ALTIMETER           12-34       123AB        1       2
1234567890ABC   LIGHT SENSOR BACK   78-45       ABC12        0       1`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read.fwf` function (*read a table of fixed width formatted data into a data.frame*) is what you're looking for. With your example above:

```
read.fwf(file = "test", widths = c(16, 20, 12, 13, 8, 1), strip.white = T)

             V1                V2    V3    V4 V5 V6
1 123A456B789C0       RADIO PANEL 95-17 AB123  0  1
2 0987AB654321C         ALTIMETER 12-34 123AB  1  2
3 1234567890ABC LIGHT SENSOR BACK 78-45 ABC12  0  1
```

`file` is your source file, `widths` is an integer vector with the successive widths of all columns, and you can add `strip.white = T` so that unnecessary spaces are trimmed for each value.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I need